# Translation to Predicate Logic with Lexicon

Tags: nlp, logic, predicate

How would one translate the following statement into predicate logic:

"*Even though the examiner hopes all students will satisfy the requirements for grade E or better, somebody will receive a lower grade and be disappointed*."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to define an alphabet. Take the following first-order alphabet with the desired interpretation:

> Unary predicates:
>
> - S(x): "x is a student"
> - E(x): "x is an examiner"
> - G(x): "x is a grade"
> - D(x): "x is disappointed"
>
> Binary predicates:
>
> - R(x, y): "x is a requirement for y"
> - B(x, y): "x is y or better"
> - O(x, y): "x receives y"
>
> Ternary predicates:
>
> - H(x, y, z): "x hopes that y fulfills z"
>
> e: Constant ("the grade E")
>
> x, y, z, w: Variables

Let's break the original statement in two parts:

> S1: "The examiner hopes all students will satisfy the requirements for grade E or better"
>
> S2: "Somebody will receive a lower grade and be disappointed"

And use the defined alphabet to write it in first-order:

> S1: ∃x(E(x) ∧ ∀y(S(y) ⇒ ∃z∃w(R(z, e) ∧ B(w, z) ∧ H(x, y, w))))
>
> S2: ∃x∃y(S(x) ∧ G(y) ∧ O(x, y) ∧ ¬B(y, e) ∧ D(x))

Finally we compute the original statement, that is:

> S1 ∧ S2

Keep in mind that this is just one of the interpretations that will lead to a correct (satisfying) answer.

I hope it helps

Comment: I kind agree with your solution, but my professor seems not to. His comments:  

"The H predicate need to be made more generalised and the L predicate need to be generalised so it could work for any situation where somebody's grade is to be referred to as lower than some other grade."

Comment: He then suggested a lexicon for the problem: 

E(x): ’x is an examiner’
S(x): ’x is a student’
G(x): ’x is a grade’
R(x, y): ’x is a requirement for y’
B(x, y): ’x is y or better’
H(x, y, z): ’x hopes that y fulfills z’
O(x, y): ’x receives y’
D(x): ’x is disappointed’
’E’: ’grade E’ (this is a constant)

Comment: @Hélder your original question don't mention this requirement that your professor pointed out. I have updated the answer with the professor suggestions though